# Calculate $f'(\sqrt{\pi})+g'(\sqrt{\pi})$ of the integrals $f(x)=(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt)^2$ and $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}}{1+t^2}dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

So I need to calculate $f'(\sqrt{\pi})+g'(\sqrt{\pi})$ of the integrals $f(x)=(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt)^2$ and $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}}{1+t^2}dt$

First I used differentiation under the integral sign rule and try to solve it,

for the first integral , I got $f'(x)=2 (\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt) e^{-x}$, then $f'(\sqrt\pi)=2 (\int_{0}^{\sqrt\pi}e^{-t^2}dt) e^{-\sqrt\pi}$. Now I don't know how to solve the integral from $0$ to $\sqrt\pi$. I am also unable to solve the next integral as well, as same integral occurs after differentiantion. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)^{2} \implies f'(x)=2e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$$
\begin{align*}
g'(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( e^{-x^{2}(1+t^{2})}\right)}{1+t^{2}}dt&=-\int_{0}^{1}2xe^{-x^{2}(1+t^{2})}dt\\
&=-2xe^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2t^2}dt\\
&=-2e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-z^{2}}dz\qquad \text{substituting  $xt=z$}
\end{align*}
Hence $f'(x)+g'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

your first integral is wrong,first integral is for the fundamental theorem  of calculus and the chain rule, equal to:
$$f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)^{2} =>f'(x)=-2xe^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$$
this integral don't have analytic solution for x finite, just numerical, then the result is in term of the integral.
The second function:
$$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^{2}(1+t^{2})}}{1+t^{2}}dt$$
using the Liebniz rule, the differential go to inside the integral, because this not depends of $x$:
$$g'(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left( e^{-x^{2}(1+t^{2})}\right)}{1+t^{2}}dt=-\int_{0}^{1}2xe^{-x^{2}(1+t^{2})}dt$$
finally the solution is:
$$f'(\sqrt{\pi})+g'(\sqrt{\pi})=-2\sqrt{\pi} e^{-\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^{2}}dt-2\sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\pi(1+t^{2})}dt=$$
$$=-4\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi}\left(\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\pi t^{2}}dt+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: But the answer provided for this question is $0$. 
See 36  http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/GATE2016questions/S4_MA.pdf
Answer key http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/GATE2016_ans_keys_final/MA_AnsKey.pdf